# postgres query timeout issue while using connection pooling in JBoss

Tags: postgresql, jboss, timeout, datasource, connection-pooling

I am facing the below issue

```
ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
```

inconsistently after I enabled query timeout for xa datasource in my xxx-ds.xml. I have added the following in my ds xml file.

```
 <query-timeout>180</query-timeout>
```

- The query timeout is set for 180 seconds, which means any sql query
  that takes more than 180 seconds will get cancelled from application
  server side.

  But the issue I am facing is inconsistent and the queries gets timed out now and then without taking exactly 180 seconds. 
  We are using connection pooling also.

While searching stackoverflow found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114101/postgresql-error-canceling-statement-due-to-user-request) question, which discusses about the possible causes for this issue while using connection pooling.

The  solution suggested there was to set statement_timeout setting in postgresql.conf file. But it is bit difficult for me to enable statement_timeout setting in my database environment as the DB server is shared by multiple applications.
I would like to have a solution to terminate timed out queries from client side effectively and consistently while using connection pooling. I am using

- JBoss 4.2.2-GA
- postgresql 9.2 (64 bit)
- java 1.7
- postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar

Comment: There is something missing in your question. Please add the details (you wrote "issue below" but there is no issue mentioned)

Comment: ERROR: canceling statement due to user request is expected to receive when a statement executes more than query-timeout. But I too faced similar issue. eg: I have to process 80000 rows and update. Client fetches all rows and calls process() EJB method on server for each row. ie, for each row processing there is separate xa-transaction for each. So all will work until the timeout and the row processed after timeout gets this error. It is expected for single statement but it turned out for all similar statements. My datasource configuration also have pooling enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with postgresql driver 9.2. When I upgraded to 9.3, issue is fixed.

Comment: Yeah. The issue is fixed when I upgraded my postgres jdbc driver to postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar